# Calculate average index-to-index ratio in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a statistical problem that I want to solve with R. Suppose I have 2 indexes, Index1 describing average price levels over time, Index2 describing average rent levels over time.

Here is my data (frame):

```
Year    Index1  Index2
1995    100     77.0033
1996    106.63  79.3342
1997    110.45  81.8608
1998    114.4   84.0633
1999    121.75  86.1133
2000    130.59  88.7758
2001    148.85  91.4483
2002    161.43  93.9042
2003    179.39  95.57
2004    204.59  97.1075
2005    227.58  99.9995
2006    253.17  102.2792
2007    277.45  104.0525
2008    276.42  107.1633
2009    261.26  109.8667
2010    280.81  111.9058
2011    295.91  114.0408
2012    306.63  115.56
2013    NA      117.2691
2014    NA      118.2967
```

Edit: I want to calculate the average of price-to-rent, in other words the long-time average ratio of Index1 / Index2. Afterwards I want to calculate the percentage-difference (every year) to the mean. How can I do that?

Best regards,
Gilles

Edit: Here is the dput(df)

```
structure(list(Year = c(1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 
2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
2013, 2014), Price = c("100", "106.63", "110.45", "114.4", "121.75", 
"130.59", "148.85", "161.43", "179.39", "204.59", "227.58", "253.17", 
"277.45", "276.42", "261.26", "280.81", "295.91", "306.63", "NA", 
"NA"), Rent = c(77.0033, 79.3342, 81.8608, 84.0633, 86.1133, 
88.7758, 91.4483, 93.9042, 95.57, 97.1075, 99.9995, 102.2792, 
104.0525, 107.1633, 109.8667, 111.9058, 114.0408, 115.56, 117.2691, 
118.2967)), .Names = c("Year", "Price", "Rent"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: if you want a new colum with index2 starting at 100, you can do df['index2_base100'] <- df$index2/df$index2[1]*100

Comment: @agenis wow! thanks for this tip. I always did this way more complicated :)
But what if there are NA values?

Comment: what do you mean by "long time" ratio? it's better if you post the expected result for a better understanding

Comment: I am not sure about the output. My goal is something like this: 
[link](http://www.housingviews.com/2012/06/07/price-to-rent-ratio/price-to-rent0312/)
The average being the line at 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the required output you posted in the comment, i can suggest this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
df              <- data.frame(apply(df, 2, as.numeric))
df['Rent_b100'] <- df$Rent/df$Rent[1]*100
df['ratio']     <- with(df, Price/Rent_b100)
average_ratio   <- mean(df$ratio, na.rm=T)

ggplot(data=df) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=Year, y=ratio), color="blue", size=2) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=average_ratio, color="purple",size=2) +
  geom_text(data=data.frame(y=c(2, 1.2), x=mean(df$Year), label=c("rent", "buy")), 
            aes(x=x, y=y, label=label), size=8) +
  geom_text(aes(x=df$Year[1], y=average_ratio*1.05, label=round(average_ratio, 2)), color="purple")
```

Which gives the following graph:
[image]

Comment: I'm impressed! Thanks :)

Comment: But I still have the problem of NA coercion if I want to use "my" data from .xlsx file

Comment: i edited my code so that you can use the data you pasted with 'dput'. I only get the warning message but no error or extra NAs.

Comment: Thanks. I used a .csv file now and it works fine... Nice code. I clearly see that I must learn a lot in R ^^

Comment: I had a problem with "," separators. Solved it like this:
df = as.double(gsub(",",".",df))

Answer (score 1):

If I do get your point, you first want to average `Index1/Index2`, ie (suppose your dataframe is `df`) :

```
average = mean(df$Index1/df$Index2, na.rm = TRUE)
```

and then to add a column in your dataframe to show the annual variation (increase is positive for example) :

```
df$variation = df$Index1/df$Index2/average - 1
```

Comment: I get an average of 1.983 with R but 1.627785 with excel. If I check, the R value corresponds to the median value. This bugs me :/

Comment: I also get an error message calculating the average: `Error in df$Index1/df$Index2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: Your Price is not numeric ; try before averaging `df$Price = as.numeric(df$Price)`

Comment: Thanks, way better now! :) Is the error message `NAs introduced by coercion` generic?

Comment: it is because in this case the strings `"NA"` are replaced by actuel NAs values

Comment: If I use `df$Price = as.numeric(df$Price)` I get only NA values for my vector :/